# JSLint/JS Formatter for Kate

Tags: text-editor, kate

I recently switched from Win7 and Notepad++ to Ubuntu and Kate. Everything seems ok, except that I am missing JS Lint and JS Format plugin of Notepad++ on my Kate. The docs are not that much helpful.

Can someone point me to the right direction if they are available.

Thanks...

Answer (score -1):

The Python package [Kate Plugins](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/Kate-plugins) contains a JSlint. The link given also has installation instructions.

Personally, I prefer the cross-platform [Sublime Text 2](http://www.sublimetext.com/2) editor.

Comment: Thanks for your link. It came up on my search and I thought it is python specific plugin. will give a try. As far sublime, the reason I switch from Win7 is to cut the cost of the company, not that I dislike win7. I am currently evaluating gVIM: powerful but invest lot of my time on learning, Kate: much similar to my familiar NP++ and Geane; another candidate with all the goodness of NP++.

Comment: Understand and sympathise with your reasoning on the switch. Of course, if time is money as "they" say, Windows may still be cheaper! But not for all use cases. gVIM and VIM/VI in general makes me shudder! I've tried GVIM several times but I just can't get on with it. Before I used Sublime, I used to use Kate on KDE desktops. Now I tend to use Gnome - Gedit is similar to Kate. And yes, NP++ was my Windows choice before I discovered Sublime. I've also used the free Komodo Edit as well for development - it's pretty good and also is cross-platform.